# ReactJs Library that installs globally

Tags: reactjs

I'm wanting to create a React library that I can build locally and that deploys into the NPM global area.  I want to be able to use my other React project that also sits on my machine and picks up changes as I modify the library.  I have found plenty of tutorials that either deploy to NPM (which I don't want) or that I have no idea how to get it updating automatically to my project.  I tried one with rollup.js that seemed to work for a while but then stopped for some reason.

Ideally looking for tutorial or source code that I can look at.

**Do's:** build locally, automatically update changes to my project

**Don'ts:** deploy to NPM or another external repository, cause problems when setup on another machine

**Want:** One library, one project, easy update to the project when the library is changed, be able to create an entry in the global install with the library version

Thanks
Paul

Comment: you want to read up on the `npm link` command. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-link, https://medium.com/dailyjs/how-to-use-npm-link-7375b6219557, etc.

Comment: I tried link with the rollup but updates didn't seem to come through

Comment: remember that the other projects need to rerun npm install because, just like for any other npm dependency, you don't get the new code unless you rerun npm install so your locally cached `./node_modules` copy gets updated.

Comment: I redid the link to to the rollup library and it still doesn't get the changes.